# Adding a completion handler on a delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

I am having a hard time understanding completion handlers. I am trying to have a function (purchaseRequest) wait until another function (didReceiveResponse) which is not called by me, but as a delegate, is done. Can somebody give me a pointer on how to accomplish this?

```
func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("response received")
    if response.products.count != 0 {
        productsArray = response.products[0]
        print(productsArray)
    } else { print("No Products Found") }
}

func purchaseRequest() {
    requestProductInfo()

    //NEED TO HOLD UNTIL didReceiveResponse (which, as a delegate method, is not called by me) IS DONE.
        print("Product1: \(self.productsArray)")
    let aSC = UIAlertController(title: "Premium App Required", message: "Premium App is Required for this feature. Would you like to purchase it for $0.99?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
    let buyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Purchase", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in
        let payment = SKPayment(product: self.productsArray)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)

    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (action) -> Void in
    }
    aSC.addAction(buyAction)
    aSC.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(aSC, animated: true, completion:  nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• push a progress spinner view controller

• make `purchaseRequest` return immediately after `requestProductInfo()`

• capture the code after `requestProductInfo()` in a new method

• in the delegate method, `dispatch_async()` to the main queue and call the new method

• in the new method, pop the spinner view controller and then do your premium purchase dance

Comment: Thanks! What I did was call requestProductInfo() and then make the purchaseRequest inside the didReceiveResponse delegate with dispatch_async()!

Comment: @JacoboKoenig Great!  Be careful of the "It's blocks all the way down" trap;   callback handlers that call async methods passing in a callback handler that calls another method with a callback handler. (I'm quite guilty as charged).  At some point, you want to refactor out the callback handler into its own method and then call that.